# How to check whether a dictionary is nested - python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, conditional-statements

**DON'T FORGET, SEE MY SELF-ANSWER BELOW**

Let's say i have a dictionary called `d`:

```
d = {'a': {1: (1,2,3), 2: (4,5,6)},'b': {1: (3,2,1), 2: (6,5,4)}}
```

As you can see, it is a nested dictionary, how would i detect if it is?

---

Here are some examples:

```
d = {'a':{1:(1,2,3),2:(4,5,6)},'b':{1:(3,2,1),2:(6,5,4)}}
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

I want the output:

```
True
False
```

P.S. list of dictionaries don't count.

Comment: what if you have a value which is a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That doesn't count.

Comment: be careful when posting a Q&A, you're getting downvotes because your question is "too broad" when you're providing the self answer below. And most people don't see the self-answered aspect.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yup, i edited mine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
print(any(isinstance(i,dict) for i in d.values()))
```

First dictionary will return:

```
True
```

Second will:

```
False
```

**To explain:**

1. Go and iterate trough `d`'s values.
2. Use `isinstance` to check whether if the type is `dict` or not.
3. Use an outer `any` to check if there are any elements that are `True` (are dictionaries).

There you go now, it will work.

Comment: You don't need square brackets any way. This would suffice: `any(isinstance(i,dict) for i in d.values())`.